# MYSQL: SELECT sum of field values while also SELECTing unique values?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'd like to count the number of purchases of each item while also, depending on who's viewing the content, show whether the user has purchased the content. Because the number of items and purchases could become large I'm reluctant to throw in more `JOINs` to accomplish this because that would seem not performant.

Basically, I'd like to have a `did_i_buy` field somewhere in the following query without adding another `JOIN`. Is this possible? Let's say for `user_name=tom`:

```
SELECT Items.item_id, item_name, COUNT(purchase_status='bought') as number_bought 
FROM Purchases
JOIN Items ON Purchases.item_id=Items.item_id
GROUP BY Items.item_id
```

Here's my DB structure:

```
Table Items
item_id item_name
1           item_1
2           item_2
3           item_3

Table Purchases
item_id  purchase_status    user_name
1           bought          joe
2           bought          joe
1           bought          tom
1           bought          bill
```

Desired result for `tom`

```
item_id item_name number_bought did_i_buy
1        item_1         3        yes
2        item_2         1        no
```

Comment: Why not denormalize "times_purchased" and do a single join for the user's bought status?

Comment: @landons, thanks, I'm not very experienced with MYSQL therefore I'm not sure what you mean by this. Can you explain with some code?

Comment: You do not need to get did_i_buy from MySql. It is a waste of resources. Just check the count > 0 in your PHP (or other language) code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the `did_i_buy` column means "did Tom buy". You can do that like this:

```
SELECT
  Items.item_id,
  item_name,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN purchase_status='bought' THEN 1 END) as number_bought,
  MAX(CASE WHEN purchase_status='bought' AND user_name='Tom' THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END) AS did_i_buy
FROM Purchases
JOIN Items ON Purchases.item_id=Items.item_id
GROUP BY Items.item_id
```

**Alternatively (one `CASE` statement, see comments below)**

```
SELECT
  Items.item_id,
  item_name,
  COUNT(purchase_status='bought') as number_bought,
  MAX(CASE WHEN user_name='Tom' THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END) AS did_i_buy
FROM Purchases
JOIN Items ON Purchases.item_id=Items.item_id
WHERE purchase_status='bought'
GROUP BY Items.item_id
```

**And one more tweak:** Because of the `WHERE` clause, the `COUNT` is only going to see rows where `purchase_status='bought'`, so the expression checking the status can be left out (the only change from above is in line 4):

```
SELECT
  Items.item_id,
  item_name,
  COUNT(*) as number_bought,
  MAX(CASE WHEN user_name='Tom' THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END) AS did_i_buy
FROM Purchases
JOIN Items ON Purchases.item_id=Items.item_id
WHERE purchase_status='bought'
GROUP BY Items.item_id
```

Comment: -@EdGibbs thanks, yes in this case `did_i_by` means "did Tom buy". Would you expect this code to perform better than using an additional `JOIN` on `Purchases` table to grab `did_i_buy` if we were talking a large number of rows? I always hear `JOINs` are bad but have no experience with large datasets.

Comment: If you use a JOIN you'll change the `number_bought` count, because it will be filtered down to just the rows matching the join. So this is the normal way to do this.

Comment: That's a tough one to answer, but in this case I think avoiding the `JOIN` is best because the `did_i_buy` is a subset of `number_bought` so you already have to scan all the rows where `purchase_status='bought'`. You can probably speed this up by adding `WHERE purchase_status='bought'` because you wouldn't be performing two `CASE` commands against non-"bought" rows.

Comment: thanks @EdGibbs, I added your putatively better code to your answer. Does that look right? If so I will accept your answer.

Comment: Thanks Tim. You don't need the expression in `COUNT(purchase_status='bought') as number_bought` because the `WHERE` is already getting rid of rows where `purchase_status <> 'bought'`. So you can save a calculation by just using `COUNT(*)`. I'll update.

Comment: OK, updated now, and thanks for the feedback and edits :) BTW - great question!

Answer (score 0):

You must (I think) use subqueries. Each request for a count is a separate query, so there is no way to optimize this (except to compress it all into one query with subqueries). There is no special relation between the horizontal data in items with the vertical data in purchases.

Here is an example query to count transactions for users:

```
SELECT user_id,(SELECT count(*) FROM transactions WHERE buyer_id=u.user_id) as count FROM users as u
```

I did a comparison with this query versus a similar query of the other JOIN type. The result: 0.0005 for this one vs. 0.0018 Ed Gibbs. However, if sorting of the number_bought (ORDER BY count DESC) is required, the latter query is significantly faster.