# MYSQL query that sums all values while also selecting one value with joined tables

Tags: php, mysql, case

When fetching an article, I would like to get sum of likes from another table and also check at the same time whether the current user has liked the article.

To get just the article and sum of likes, I can do:

```
"SELECT a.id AS aid,a.title,a.slug,SUM(l.likes) AS likes  
FROM articles `a` 
LEFT JOIN likes `l` 
ON l.articleid = a.id 
WHERE a.id = 33";
```

How can I simultaneously get whether the current user has liked the article.

The logic for whether the user has liked the article would be

`"SELECT like FROM likes where articleid = 33 AND userid = 22"`

where if the count of rows == 0 then the user has not liked the article.

However, I'm not sure how to integrate that into the first query. I think it might involve using CASE, but this is above my level of SQL familiarity. Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT a.id AS aid,
       a.title,
       a.slug,
       SUM(l.likes) AS likes,
       SUM(l.userid = 22) AS is_liked
FROM articles `a` 
LEFT JOIN likes `l` ON l.articleid = a.id 
WHERE a.id = 33
```

Comment: Thanks. For anyone who reads this another approach that I found to work (accepted answer, version with single Case statement) can be found here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17029106/mysql-select-sum-of-field-values-while-also-selecting-unique-values